# Is Zoom in disabled in TeXshop?

Tags: texshop

In the TexShop editor environment. You used to be able to zoom in to make characters larger by press "CMD +"

Every time I tried to enlarge the source menu just highlights.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You now have to select all before zooming in.  See https://pages.uoregon.edu/koch/texshop/version.html

Comment: Wow, I can't believe this all happened under my nose.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

Press `Command`, `A` and `=` together in the keyboard.  `=` is the zoom in controller